# Best way to inject instance of DynamoDBContext in .NET Core

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, amazon-dynamodb

Currently working on a web services project for my class and have decided to make a web API using .NET Core and DynamodDB.

I was just curious what the best way to inject the `DynamoDBContext` is?

I currently am doing it like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddDefaultAWSOptions(Configuration.GetAWSOptions());
    services.AddAWSService<IAmazonDynamoDB>();
}
```

I got this piece of code above from the DynamoDB documentation. I add an instance of `IAmazonDynamoDB` to the project.

```
DynamoDBContext context;
public ValuesController(IAmazonDynamoDB context)
{
    this.context = new DynamoDBContext(context);
}
```

In the controller, I then inject the `IAmazonDynamoDB` instance, and use that to create an instance of `DynamoDBContext`.

Is there a way to create an instance of the context in the `ConfigureServices` method and add it to the project there, or is the way I am doing it currently fine?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Is there a way to create an instance of the context in the
>   ConfigureServices method and add it to the project there, or is the
>   way I am doing it currently fine?

Although your solution will work, it has a drawback. You're not using Dependency Injection for `DynamoDBContext` and create its instance in controller constructor through `new` operator. You'll face a problems when it comes to unit testing your code, because you have no way to substitute implementation of `DynamoDBContext`.

The proper way is to register `DynamoDBContext` in DI container and let the container itself create an instance when it's required. With such approach `IDynamoDBContext` gets injected into `ValuesController`:

```
public class ValuesController
{
    private readonly IDynamoDBContext context;

    public ValuesController(IDynamoDBContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    // ...
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddDefaultAWSOptions(Configuration.GetAWSOptions());
    services.AddAWSService<IAmazonDynamoDB>();
    services.AddTransient<IDynamoDBContext, DynamoDBContext>();
}
```

Comment: That worked! Yeah I realized my solution did not use dependency injection, which is what prompted me to ask this question here. I thought I tried just adding a singleton of the dynamodb context in my configure services method, but I must have done something incorrectly there because I was getting some error saying that it was not propery instantiated or something like that.

Either way, thank you for the help!

Comment: Looks like from the [doc here](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/using-amazon-dynamodb-object-persistence-framework-an-introduction/), "*The DynamoDBContext object is thread-safe, so it is a good idea to construct it once per application and reuse it.*".
So the above registration can be `AddSingleton` instead of `AddTransient`

Answer (score 5):

Basically you'd have to create an interface for your DynamoDB context

```
public interface IDynamoDbContext<T> : IDisposable where T : class
{
    Task<T> GetByIdAsync(string id);
    Task SaveAsync(T item);
    Task DeleteByIdAsync(T item);
}
```

Create a class implementing the interface

```
public class DynamoDbContext<T> : DynamoDBContext, IDynamoDbContext<T>
    where T : class
{
    public DynamoDbContext(IAmazonDynamoDB client)
        : base(client)
    {

    }

    public async Task<T> GetByIdAsync(string id)
    {
        return await base.LoadAsync<T>(id);
    }

    public async Task SaveAsync(T item)
    {
        await base.SaveAsync(item);
    }

    public async Task DeleteByIdAsync(T item)
    {
        await base.DeleteAsync(item);
    }
}
```

Inject it in your Startup like this

```
var client = Configuration.GetAWSOptions().CreateServiceClient<IAmazonDynamoDB>();
services.AddScoped<IDynamoDbContext<AwesomeClass>>(provider => new DynamoDbContext<AwesomeClass>(client));
```

The context will be passed in the DI system and you can use it where you like

```
private IDynamoDbContext<AwesomeClass> _awesomeContext;

public AwesomeDynamoDbService(IDynamoDbContext<AwesomeClass> awesomeContext)
{
    _awesomeContext= awesomeContext;
}
```

I faced a similar issue and wrote a [blog post](http://underscorehao.net/2018/03/net-core-api-dynamodb-dependency-injection/) describing a good way to fix it! Hope it shares some light!

Comment: and how you set the table name ?

Comment: @Kob_24 The table name is controlled by the model. In this case, the model is whatever type `item` is and the class name will be used as the table name. If the class is decorated with the `DynamoDBTableAttribute`, its value will be used for the table name instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I am using it to make it work with both local & public (AWS hosted) DynamoDB.

**appsettings.Development.json**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AWS": {
    "Profile": "default",
    "Region": "ap-south-1"
  },
  "DynamoDb": {
    "LocalMode": false,
    "LocalServiceUrl": "http://localhost:8001",
    "TableNamePrefix": ""
  }
}
```

**Program.cs in .NET 6**

```
// Get the AWS profile information from configuration providers
AWSOptions awsOptions = builder.Configuration.GetAWSOptions();

// Configure AWS service clients to use these credentials
builder.Services.AddDefaultAWSOptions(awsOptions);

var dynamoDbConfig = builder.Configuration.GetSection("DynamoDb");
var runLocalDynamoDb = dynamoDbConfig.GetValue<bool>("LocalMode");

#region DynamoDB setup
if (runLocalDynamoDb)
{
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAmazonDynamoDB>(sp =>
    {
        var clientConfig = new AmazonDynamoDBConfig { ServiceURL = dynamoDbConfig.GetValue<string>("LocalServiceUrl") };
        return new AmazonDynamoDBClient(clientConfig);
    });
}
else
{
    builder.Services.AddAWSService<IAmazonDynamoDB>();
}

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDynamoDBContext, DynamoDBContext>((serviceProvider) =>
{
    IAmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDBClient = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IAmazonDynamoDB>();
    DynamoDBContextConfig dynamoDBContextConfig = new DynamoDBContextConfig
    {
        TableNamePrefix = dynamoDbConfig.GetValue<string>("TableNamePrefix")
    };
    return new DynamoDBContext(amazonDynamoDBClient, dynamoDBContextConfig);
});
#endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Lambda then you can try ti use below code

In your DynamoDB database class add constructor with dependency on `IDynamoDBContext`

```
public DynamoDbDatabase(IDynamoDBContext dynamoDbContext)
{            
    _dynamoDbContext = dynamoDbContext;                           
}
```

In Function.cs of your Lambda define mapping for dependency injection

```
private static IServiceProvider ConfigureServices()
{
    var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();            
    serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IDynamoDBContext,DynamoDBContext>(p => new DynamoDBContext(new AmazonDynamoDBClient()));  
    return serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider(); 
}
```

Call above function on top of your lambda function handler

when your code runs it will automatically detect dependency and pass proper `DynamoDBContext` object when asked for `IDynamoDBContext`